# Tag-it Autocomplete: Make li.tagit-new cover rest of ul.tagit

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, tag-it

I tried to get the 'li.tagit-new input' to cover the full width of the rest of the parent ul.tagit with:

```
ul.tagit li {
    display:table-cell;
    white-space:nowrap;
    vertical-align:top;
    float: none;
}

ul.tagit li.tagit-new {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
ul.tagit li.tagit-new input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

It works fine if there is at least one tag. But not if there no tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/bus9dgx5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i cant write this as a comment. as i understand ur problem , u can display it with the flex proprety

```
ul.tagit {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
}
```

here is a demo

http://jsfiddle.net/4eusrdbf/1/

Comment: But if there is no tag ... the input still doesn't cover the whole width. I have a .ui-autocomplete-loading on the far right of the input ... and if there is no tag ... it's somewhere in the middle ...

Comment: the input doesnt cover the whole width , it just give illusion that it does because we dont see the borders, the ui-autocomplete-loading on the far right will be always in the right if there is no tag too, u can see this on the jsfiddle . if im not understanding ur problem can u please post a photo ?

Comment: For some reason the .ui-autocomplete-loading is not appearing in jsfiddle so I attached it to .ui-autocomplete-input : http://jsfiddle.net/4eusrdbf/ When there is no tag its somewhere in the middle ... So that's why I want the input to cover the whole width ...

Comment: Hi Philipp , here is the updated Jsfiddle , i fixed it using the flex proprety http://jsfiddle.net/4eusrdbf/1/ , if this solve your problem please tell me to edit my response that can mark it to green , thanks :)

Comment: Yes perfect. That's what I hoped for. :-) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perfect , i have updated my answer @PhilippM, please mark it with green :)

Comment: Just did !! :-)